# Updating Dataframe during Traversal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

I'm working with dataframes, and need to delete a few rows as I iterate through them.

A brief overview: I read a row (N), compare it with the next 20 rows (till N+20), and delete a few rows between N and N+20 based on the comparison. I then go back to N+1, and compare that row with the next 20 rows, until N+1+20. **I do not want to compare N+1 with the rows I've previously deleted.**

However, as I delete the rows, the deletion is not reflected in the dataframe as I am traversing its original copy, and the change hasn't been reflected.
Any solutions for this?

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\snip\test.csv")
index_to_delete = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    snip

    for i in range(20):
        if (index + i + 1) < len(df.index):
            if condition:
                index_to_delete.append(index + i + 1) #storing indices of rows to delete between N and N+20

    df.loc[index, ['snip1', 'snip2']] = [snip, snip] #updating values in row N
    df = df.drop(index_to_delete)
    index_to_delete.clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

there are a many tricks to solve ploblem:

1: you can itrate over len of `df` instead of itrate on `df`.

```
for inx in range(len(df)):
    try:
        row = df.loc[inx]
    except:
        continue
```

2: store checked indexes and skip them

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\snip\test.csv")
all_index_to_delete = []
index_to_delete = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index in all_index_to_delete:
        continue
    snip

    for i in range(20):
        if (index + i + 1) < len(df.index):
            if condition:
                index_to_delete.append(index + i + 1) #storing indices of rows to delete between N and N+20
                all_index_to_delete.append(index + i + 1) #storing indices of rows to delete between N and N+20

    df.loc[index, ['snip1', 'snip2']] = [snip, snip] #updating values in row N
    df = df.drop(index_to_delete)
    index_to_delete.clear()
```